# Getting unexpected token: a left angle bracket error in lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am using `<aura:iteration>` to generate a datatable. But I am continuously getting the error:

> aura/Select_List_For_Message/Select_List_For_Message.cmp -- Error:
>   unexpected token: a left angle bracket at column 1 of expression:
>   lt['list_name'] (line N/A column N/A)

Below is the code snippet I am getting the error. Really not sure what is being wrong:

**Attribute definition:**

```
<aura:attribue name="lists" type="Send_Email_Controller.List_Helper[]"/>
```

**Table:**

```
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate">Send</div>
                </th>
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.lists}" var="lt">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!lt.isSend}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!lt['list_name']}</div>
                    </td>
```

As you can see here, I have already tried {!lt.isSend} and lt['list_name'] ways here. But neither one worked for me.

The answer should be something simple. But I just can't figure out.

**Edit**

List_helper is a wrapper class defined inside original VF page controller, which is also my lightning component server side controller now. The definition is as below:

```
public class Send_Email_Controller 
{
    //...
    public class List_Helper
    {
        public String list_name {get; set;}
        public String folder_name {get; set;}
        public Boolean isSend {get; set;}
        public Boolean unsent {get; set;}
        public Decimal v6_id {get; set;}

        public List_Helper()
        {
            isSend = false;
            unsent = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check the spelling of aura:attribue

Comment: @SantanuBoral You are right. I spelled aura:attribute wrong. But after I fixed it, I am still seeing the same error though.

Comment: @LanceShi What's the definition of List_Helper?

Comment: @sfdcfox I edited my answer and put the code in.

Comment: @LanceShi One more thing. What's the error? I managed to get an Internal Server Error when I try to replicate your situation.

Comment: @sfdcfox The error is what I put in the question: Failed to save undefined: unexpected token: a left angle bracket at column 1 of expression: lt.isSend: Source

Comment: @sfdcfox I guess Praveen got the reason now. It is because lt is not a good name.

Comment: @LanceShi Sorry, I should have clarified. What happens when you do `{!lt.list_name}` instead?

Comment: @LanceShi Ah. Literally the name lt... possibly reserved? I usually recommend more descriptive variables anyways, but this was definitely good to know.

Comment: @sfdcfox It is probably kind of reserved in html. lt probably means < in html and I guess why it is always telling there is an unexpected < in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only reference the object property using dot notation only in Lightning Component.

Looks like using `var="lt"`, Lightning component compiles it as `<`(left angle bracket), so change the var to something else : `var="list"`.

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.lists}" var="list">
       <div>{!list['list_name']}</div> // not supported
       <div>{!list.list_name}</div> // supported
 <aura:iteration>
```

Comment: `[]` is for static index access on an array.

Comment: Thank you for this. But actually I tried both ways. And neither one works for me.

Comment: @LanceShi are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Yes, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @LanceShi I was able to reproduce the error, change `var="lt"` to something else like `var="list"`

Comment: @Praveen Cool. Thank you for that. I seems lt is not a good name.